# vBulletin Default Usergroup upon Registration add-on doesn't work

Tags: drupal, vbulletin

I'm traying to make this add-on work on vBulletin 3.6.8
http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?p=2375613

It doesn't seem to work. Newly registered users are not assigned to the custom group which I wanted.

Here is what I'm trying to do http://www.ajaykumarsingh.com/vbulletin/vbulletin-how-to-moderate-first-post-from-new-users.html

My forum is conencted to Drupal using drupalvb module, may this is the reason?

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I will be posting this as if you were new to vbulletin. I am not saying that you are or trying to insult. One is that the mod could not be capatiable with your version. The dupalvb bridge, it may be causing the issue. Have you tried disabling the plugin and continuing?